# Problem in getting geocode of hong kong in python

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

In python(Jupyter notebook) 'getGeoCode' which has "getGeoBoundry(location_name)" function.For this question you need API access.

It returns json format like the following:
{u'northeast': {u'lat': 22.5619469, u'lng': 114.4294999}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 22.1435, u'lng':
113.8259001}} with location_name = “Hong Kong”

For help:-https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

I am not able to write the function in python for that?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question / problem? What do you need help with? Also check out related thread for geocoding example in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003274/python-google-maps-api-timeouterror-errno-60-operation-timed-out-when-cal

Comment: I check the related link and that is quite useful to me. But when I am running in Google colab it is showing this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geocode'. Please fix it.

Comment: Did you set it up exactly as I did? As in, do you have a file named "geocode" (.py) with my exact code, and are you calling the getGeocodeLocation function from main.py?

Comment: Can you tell me how to run this program in .ipnyb (Google colab)?

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and give you a full answer, give me a min.

Answer (score 0):

To geocode "Hong Kong", just add the following code (which is based off of the code from [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59003274/11742502)) to a cell within your Google colab notebook:

```
import httplib2
import json

def getGeocodeLocation(inputString):
    # Use Google Maps to convert a location into Latitute/Longitute coordinates

    google_api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    locationString = inputString.replace(" ", "+")
    url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&key=%s'% (locationString, google_api_key))
    h = httplib2.Http()
    result = json.loads(h.request(url,'GET')[1])
    latitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    longitude = result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return result;

getGeocodeLocation("Hong Kong")
```

Then click on "Run cell" and you should get the following output:

```
{'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Hong Kong',
     'short_name': 'HK',
     'types': ['country', 'political']}],
   'formatted_address': 'Hong Kong',
   'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 22.5619469,
      'lng': 114.4294999},
     'southwest': {'lat': 22.1435, 'lng': 113.8259001}},
    'location': {'lat': 22.3193039, 'lng': 114.1693611},
    'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE',
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 22.5619469, 'lng': 114.4294999},
     'southwest': {'lat': 22.1435, 'lng': 113.8259001}}},
   'place_id': 'ChIJD5gyo-3iAzQRfMnq27qzivA',
   'types': ['country', 'political']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am attaching my google colab file.Please fixed the error in that file.https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qm5aqtLBSTLUPoX4JfDtmsTQ_pzWj0sA

Comment: Your API key is not valid. This is the only difference between your code and mine and i verified this on my end. Make sure that both billing and Geocoding API are enabled on your project. See https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started