# Best way in Python3 to extract the value of "location", specifically "lat" and "lng" from this snippet?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-maps

I have this JSON output that I am attempting to parse from a Google Maps API call

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "San Diego",
          "short_name": "San Diego",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "San Diego County",
          "short_name": "San Diego County",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "California",
          "short_name": "CA",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "San Diego, CA, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 33.114249,
            "lng": -116.90816
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 32.534856,
            "lng": -117.3097969
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 32.715738,
          "lng": -117.1610838
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 33.114249,
            "lng": -116.90816
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 32.534856,
            "lng": -117.3097969
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id": "ChIJSx6SrQ9T2YARed8V_f0hOg0",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

I am trying to get the value of `location:`, specifically `lat` and `lng`. My JSON object gets dumped into this line:

```
    response = json.load(url_request.urlopen(url))
```

I can call up to `response['results']` but any further nesting doesn't allow me to index. For instance:

```
print(response['results']['address components'])
```

outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 12, in main
    get_coordinates()
  File "main.py", line 34, in get_coordinates
    print(response['results']['address+components'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Varuns-MacBook-Air:map_project varunhariharan$ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 12, in main
    get_coordinates()
  File "main.py", line 34, in get_coordinates
    print(response['results']['address components'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a list inside a dictionary. This should work:

```
lat = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["northeast"]["lat"]
lng = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["northeast"]["lng"]
# Just change "northeast" to whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, `results` is an array. Access the first result with `results[0]`.

Also see the answer to the related question: [Python / Google Maps API - TimeoutError: (Errno 60) Operation timed out when calling a function from the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59003274/python-google-maps-api-timeouterror-errno-60-operation-timed-out-when-cal)

To get latitude for the first result: `print(response['results'][0]['location']['lat']`

To get longitude for the first result: `print(response['results'][0]['location']['lng']`

Comment: Don't forget quotation marks around your keys!